can not access rest API running in docker container
I have a REST API built in .net 8. When it runs on my machine, I can test it using Postman (http://localhost:8009/api/...) without issue. But when I running it from inside a docker container, the Postman test always fails with a timeout error (I am not even getting an HTTP error).
I have tried using localhost:8009, ipofmyhost:8009, ipofthecontainer:8009 and they don't make any difference. I also tried using the service name as defined in my docker-compose.yml file (I am using docker-compose instead of dock run) without any successes either.
Here is my docker-compose.yml
version: '3.4'

services:
  myapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myapi:v.1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyTest\Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8009:80"

and here is the Docker file
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-nanoserver-ltsc2022 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8009

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-nanoserver-ltsc2022 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyTest/TPARestAPI.csproj", "TPARestAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./MyTest/./myapi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyTest"
RUN dotnet build "./myapi.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./myapi.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapi.dll"]

Any ideas?

That potentially sounds like the symptom of a container process set to listen on the container-private 127.0.0.1 localhost address; in most cases a process running in a container needs to listen on 0.0.0.0, "all interfaces".  Does your application have some sort of "listen" or "bind" configuration?

Hi Alexu, could you kindly to check if it works by using another port, like 8080 ? If it still not works, please check this official document about using host.docker.internal.

Thanks for the input! David - that does sound promissing. But, I am fairly new on docker and really not sure where the binding should go. The two files attached above are about the only places we specify ports but I really have no idea where the 0.0.0.0 should go. Once again, we are using .Net for our API development. I will reaserch on how to bind the port, but any inputs and advices will be highly appreciated.

@Alexu please check out the suggested duplicate. If it does not work/is not the source of the issue - please ping me and I will reopen the answer.

In your docker-compose file you are mapping 8009 to 80. It means your api is listening on port 80 inside container.
but your are exposing 8009 in your Dockerfile this is wrong. you need to expose port 80 inside Dockerfile as well.
But I think Your api should be listening on other port than 80.
If your api is listening on 8009 in your container then you need to expose 8009 in your Dockerfile & then you need to update your docker-compose file to map 8009 to 8009 like:
8009:8009

But that's not what the doc says. I should be able to map 8009 (external) to 80 (internal). And we have other APIs configured like that and work.
